# How to check file duplication in SP document library using REST API or jsom?

Tags: javascript, document-library, rest, duplicate

I need to check the uploading file is already exist in the document library or not by using RESt-api or jsom.
Please suggest some idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the `getfilebyserverrelativeurl` to determine whether file exists or not.

Try and modify the below code (using REST). Ensure that you are passing the server relative url of the file:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/testsite/Documents/test.txt')",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log("file exists");
    },
    error: function(error){
        if(error.status == 404){
            console.log("file doesnt exist");
        }

    }
});
```